# Why is named parameter 'not defined'?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Trying to use a named parameter in a simple sql query. Upon assigning a value to the parameter, the marameter name is flagged as undefined (NameError)

Same query works fine with positional parameter
Tried over different tables with different parameter names
Passed values directly rather than via variables

```
import sqlite3
myConn = sqlite3.connect("testDB.db")
myCursor = myConn.cursor()
myCursor.execute(
    "SELECT CourseName FROM Courses WHERE CourseName =:course",{'English':course})
print(myCursor.fetchone())
```

I should retrieve just the one line from the db.
instead I get the following error message

```
line 14, in <module>
myCursor.execute("SELECT CourseName FROM Courses WHERE CourseName =:course",{'English':course})
NameError: name 'course' is not defined
```

Comment: Try `{'course': 'English'}` instead.

Comment: thanks, that is not the problem though your comment put me on the right track. In that dictionary, the key should be the named parameter in between quotes and the value should be a variable instantiated somewhere else in the code.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a variable, you can use a string literal as well. Did you try changing it according to my comment?

Answer (score 0):

The secon argument ot the execute query is a dictionary. The key is the named parameter used in the SQL query (it needs too be in btw quotes) the value for that key is a variable instantiaded somewhere else in the code.

```
import sqlite3

myConn = sqlite3.connect("testDB.db")
myCursor = myConn.cursor()

query = "SELECT CourseName FROM Courses WHERE CourseName=:course"
test = "English"

myCursor.execute("SELECT CourseName FROM Courses WHERE CourseName =:course",{'course':test})

print(myCursor.fetchone())
```